# how to assign right values to right columns in Excel or Python

Tags: python, excel

I recently scraped the data using Python and exported the data to CSV files.
But later on I found one critical error.
Since I am a beginner at Python, I tried to find past references or some materials for me to figure this out by myself but couldn't.

Let me go straight into my problem. For example, my CSV file looks like this:

```
        amenity_TV  amenity_Wifi  amenity_kitchen  amenity_iron  ...  amenity_phone
hotel_A    TV            Wifi           kitchen        iron      ...     phone
hotel_B    TV            kitchen        iron           null      ...     null
hotel_C    TV            Wifi           iron           null      ...     null
hotel_D    Wifi          null           phone          null      ...     null
```

where the unit is hotel and amenities are columns. What I've done wrong is I should have assigned the right values at the right column. For example, the way it should be look like this:

```
        amenity_TV  amenity_Wifi  amenity_kitchen  amenity_iron  ...  amenity_phone
hotel_A    TV            Wifi           kitchen        iron      ...     phone
hotel_B    TV            null           kitchen        iron      ...     null
hotel_C    TV            Wifi           null           iron      ...     null
hotel_D    null          Wifi           null           null      ...     phone
```

One further question is can I handle this in Excel or is it more efficient to do this using Python?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's impossible to see exactly what's going wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DavidGaertner Hi David, I was just wondering if there's any way to change my current CSV file to the desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to move the values to the right column in Excel:

1. Create a new set of columns "amenity_TV", "amenity_Wifi", etc.
2. Use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace "amenity_" in each column header with a blank string, i.e. just return "TV", "Wifi", etc.
3. Check for a `MATCH` in each row against the resulting text.
4. If there is a `MATCH` - i.e. `MATCH` does not return an error - return that text, otherwise return `Null`.

---

*Original Data*

[image]

---

*Updated Data*

Put this formula in `I2` and drag across and down:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(K$1,"amenity_",""),$B2:$F2,0))),SUBSTITUTE(K$1,"amenity_",""),"Null")
```

[image]